# What are drawbacks of using wojtekmaj react-17 adapter on React 18 codebase?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I've seen multiple articles and set-ups on how to configure an application that runs React 18 to run React 17 and the wojtekmaj enzyme adapter for React 17 in the test folder ([here](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2524#issuecomment-1116246491) and [here](https://darekkay.com/blog/react-18-enzyme/)). So obviously, it *can* be done.

If one goes that route, would it properly test the application that is running React 18 code? Would things be missed such as testing new APIs from React 18 or would you just need to implement a different kind of test?

I am currently working on upgrading our application from React 16 to React 18, but if I can't properly test the code using the wojtekmaj adapter built for React 17, I will instead upgrade to React 17. We have approximately 20k unit tests, so moving those from enzyme to RTL is going to take a bit of work.

Comment: I remember trying the same thing and I ended up leaving it, I think because it required old packages that ended up being incompatible, but I cannot recall what with. So that's probably one thing to note.